# Need to Modify a Wordpress Shortcode with another wordpress shortcode

Tags: php, functions, shortcode, urls

hi I have this shortcode... 
[user_meta key="_wc_social_login_profile_image" id=3] 
It shows the image of a particular user with a special number..

I need to change the number with another shortcode I already have... 
[user_special_number]

I need the final result to be...

[user_meta key="_wc_social_login_profile_image" id="[user_special_number]"]

Comment: What about using do_shortcode inside your add_shortcode('user_meta') function? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

Comment: Im not 100% sure how to do it...  I have been doing a little with it

Comment: You can't nest shortcodes in attributes, you should consider forking the shortcode to create a brand new one

Comment: Hey Tom, how do I do that? Do you have simple example of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like this

```
ob_start();
do_shortcode("[user_special_number]");
$special_id = ob_get_clean();
```

So now you have you your special id, so let's do it again

```
ob_start();
do_shortcode('[user_meta key="_wc_social_login_profile_image" id="'.$special_id.'"]');
echo ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: `do_shortcode()` _returns_, so output buffering isn't needed at all. In the first block you can just set `$special_id` to `do_shortcode()` directly, and in the 2nd block, you can just `echo` `do_shortcode()` directly.

Comment: Hi something a little wrong with this... Im trying to get the social image of any wordpress user and display on a page... Https://graph.facebook.net/sdfsdfsdf  .... The code you give doesnt show the url... The user meta shows an image url